# can't create automatic sql tables after first use

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm new with PHP and SQL...

I'm trying to create new tables based on the url, but it's only working the first time I use it. After that, it's not possible.

Here is my PHP code:

```
 if(isset($_GET['id'])){
 $tabela = $_GET['tabela'];
 $_GET['id'];
 $criar = $tabela . $nivel . $page_id;

 // Se clicar no botão 'confirmar', então ele faz o seguinte:
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
 $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];
$texto = $_POST['texto'];


 // Se um destes campos estiver vazio:
if($titulo=='' or $imagem=='' or $texto==''){

            echo "Preencha todos os campos para o menu!";

            exit();             }

                    // Se não houver campos vazios, ele faz:            else {

            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "site";


            // Ligação à base de dados:
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


                    // Verifica a ligação:
                    if ($conn->connect_error) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                    } 

            // Cria a nova tabela:
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $criar (
                    id INT(9) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                    titulo VARCHAR(255),
                    imagem LONGBLOB,
                    texto TEXT,
                    grupo INT(9),
                    FOREIGN KEY (grupo) REFERENCES $tabela(id)
                    )";


                    // Se conseguir ligar-se à base de dados e criar uma nova tabela, ele insere os dados na nova tabela:
                    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {


                        include("includes/connect.php");
                        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

                        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"../imagens/$imagem");


                        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO $criar (titulo, imagem, texto, grupo) VALUES ('$titulo','$imagem','$texto','$page_id')";


                                // Se inserir os dados na nova tabela, ele dá uma mensagem de sucesso:
                                if(mysql_query($insert_query)){

                                    echo "<script>alert('Menu inserido com sucesso!')</script>";
                                    echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
                                }

                                else{
                                    echo "Erro: " . $insert_query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                                }
                    }



                    // Caso ele não consiga criar uma nova tabela (porque já existe), ele insere os dados na tabela já existente:
                    else {



                        include("includes/connect.php");
                        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");


                        // Cria a nova tabela:
                        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $criar (
                                id INT(9) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                                titulo VARCHAR(255),
                                imagem LONGBLOB,
                                texto TEXT,
                                grupo INT(9),
                                FOREIGN KEY (grupo) REFERENCES $tabela(id)
                                )";

                                if(mysql_query($sql)){

                                    echo "sim!";
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo "não!";
                                }

                        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"../imagens/$imagem");    

                        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO $criar (titulo, imagem, texto, grupo) VALUES ('$titulo','$imagem','$texto','$page_id')";


                                // Caso consiga inserir os dados na tabela já existente, dá uma mensagem de sucesso:
                                if(mysql_query($insert_query&&$sql)){

                                    echo "<script>alert('Menu inserido com sucesso!')</script>";
                                    echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";

                                }
                                else{

                                    echo "isto não está a correr bem!";
                                }

                    // Fecha a ligação à base de dados:
                    $conn->close();

                    }           }       }$nivel = $_GET['grupo'];       $page_id =$imagem = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];          $image_tmp =
```

Comment: stop using mysql and start using mysqli or pdo

Comment: what have you done to debug your code?

Comment: Hi. As mentioned, im new with php and mysql, so i do not wich language is the best (mysql, mysqli or pdo)... i will start trying to go with your advise (mysqli or pdo). Regarding debug, i didnt try too many things as i do not know how to do it properly.. i've removed some parts of the code, like the move_uploaded image and add some "echo" to check if it "echo" or not my phrases, but is not being enough till know to check what i should do to fix this. Az

Comment: Why would you want to create the table more then once?

Comment: Well, this is a cms for my website and i have an index page in my admin panel, which shows my default / first table and then i need to create the rest of the content based on the content of the first table using foreign keys... at my index, i have 3 buttons (create new page, delete and edit), when i say "create", it will generate a new table based on my previous table id, using foreign key, and next i will create another based on that last table and so on... because contents should be linked to the right content from the first content to the last one...

Comment: I couldnt edit my previous comment, so here is: Hi. As mentioned, im new with php and mysql, so i do not wich language is the best (mysql, mysqli or pdo)... i will start trying to go with your advise (mysqli or pdo). Regarding debug, i didnt try too many things as i do not know how to do it properly.. i've removed some parts of the code, like the move_uploaded image and add some "echo" to check if it "echo" or not my phrases, but is not being enough till know to check what i should do to fix this. As i said, this code works once, but is not working when i try to create the second table.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean 1st time, 2nd time? Do you try to create another table with the same name you just have created? You'll get a table already exists error.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $criar
```

This explicitly tells MySql not to create the table if it exists, so if you pass the same query parameters to your php then it'll not be able to create the same table again.

Probably you could change it to:

```
$page_id = $_GET['id'];
$criar = $tabela . $nivel . $page_id;
```

And then pass a different id and/or different tabela every time.

Comment: the question the OP is supposed to answer to is why would he want to create the table more then once?

Comment: OP: "but it's only working the first time I use it. After that, it's not possible." I just explained him why he experiences it.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing your answer, I wanted the OP to explain why or what he's expecting. +1 for the answer

Answer (score 0):

this code looks behind the issue to me :

```
 $tabela = $_GET['tabela'];
 $_GET['id'];  //this line looks odd 
 $criar = $tabela . $nivel . $page_id;
```

and maybe it's not creating new tables because you give the same $criar every time.

Comment: Hi. Not really... the $tabela variable is getting a new content... for instances, if im on index and click at "create a new page", the $tabela will get this info: "activecard01", $nivel will get "1" and $page_id will be "1". So at the end, the $criar variable will be "activecard0111. Right? So, the page is created and inserts the data on it. Next, when i click again on the button "create a new page", $tabela will get "activecard0111", so at the end i will have "activecard011111" for the second table... but is not working in this second time...

Comment: you can use mysqli and by adding http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php you investigate further more about the issue

Comment: i'm not being able to use this statement... :( As mentioned, i'm new at PHP, etc., so i'm not having success using it. GRRR

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying to solve this issue, i finally got good news! :) i was working in my local server (via xampp) and decided to put it online to check if something changes... and dont know why, but it works perfectly online and dont work with xampp! What a mess!! but its working!! thanks all for your help!! ;)